# how to add search query to wordpress site for searching keyword inside docouemts in PDF format

Tags: php, wordpress, pdf

I am working on a WordPress site and I want to have a WordPress search query that can **search for keyword** inside documents (PDF and MS Word format) uploaded to my WordPress site.

I have search a lot on google but I did not get any solution. 
Do you guys know about WordPress plugin that will do that?

Answer (score 0):

You looking for the Fulltext Search plugin (https://wordpress.org/plugins/fulltext-search/)

> It provides an ability to configure indexing mechanism by defining
>   special filter function. It is useful to include dynamic-generated
>   texts to seach index or, for example, read text content from MS
>   Excel/Word of Adobe PDF files to implement search in PDF files.